# Notification about a deleted question

Tags: bug, global-inbox

I posted a comment to a question. The OP answered the comment and deleted the question.

Now I get the notification about the unread comment

[image]

and if I click it I land to the page not found error. The notification counter stays at one with not way to *mark the comment as read*.

Comment: When you close the dialog it's still showing the red number? And when reloading?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It was, even by reopening the browser. Now (after 30') it is no more there (but I had the notification about your comment so I don't know if it went away because of time or because of a recount)

Comment: Interesting, though not sure it's because the question was deleted.